# CoreData fetch 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection error in swift 3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have `User` table you can see under below

```
id (Int)
name (String)
no (String)
number (Int)
```

I want to fetch it with ;

```
let predicate = NSPredicate (format:"name CONTAINS[cd] (%@) || no CONTAINS[cd] (%@) && number == 5",search.text!, search.text!)
```

Gives me ;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 0 (not a collection)'
```

Error, how can I fix it ? I want to search name and no strings with typing search text.

Comment: could you pose more code , so that we can dive inside context of problem !

Comment: @dip another codes working good when I delete || no CONTAINS[cd] (%@) working but must be .

Comment: I THINK MAYBE no row don't work ? in core data ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: You can't write `if (a || b && c)`, you need to write either  `if ((a || b) && c)` or ` `if (a || (b && c))` according to your choice.

Comment: @Larme I did  "((name CONTAINS[cd] (%@) || no CONTAINS[cd] (%@)) && number == 5)". and same error

Comment: You can't use `NO`. It's a reserved word in predicates: `The following words are reserved: AND, OR, IN, NOT, ALL, ANY, SOME, NONE, LIKE, CASEINSENSITIVE, CI, MATCHES, CONTAINS, BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH, BETWEEN, NULL, NIL, SELF, TRUE, YES, FALSE, NO, FIRST, LAST, SIZE, ANYKEY, SUBQUERY, FETCH, CAST, TRUEPREDICATE, FALSEPREDICATE, UTI-CONFORMS-TO, UTI-EQUALS,` Maybe replacing it with `%K`, and then `"no"`: `...%K CONTAINS[cd] (%@)..., "no", search.text!`, but I'm not sure at all. You may have to rename your attribute.

Comment: is `search.text` a string?